# ImportError: No module named 'PyQt4.QtWebKit'

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt4, qtwebkit

I'm trying to setup Ghost.py and I need PyQt4 for it.

I've downloaded `PyQt-x11-gpl-4.11.3` version and used `configure-ng.py` with `Python-3.4.2`, of course did `make` and `make install`.

Sadly, I'm getting an error `ImportError: No module named 'PyQt4.QtWebKit'` while trying to `from ghost import Ghost`.

Can't figure out how do I build QtWebKit.

Thank you for any useful input!

Comment: Does the system you are building on have the necessary qt webkit dev packages installed? Run `configure-ng.py` with the `--verbose` flag and see what errors it gives when trying to generate the source for the webkit modules. The output will also give a list of all the modules that wil be built.

Comment: This is what I get http://pastebin.com/VhZgTy3Z

Comment: See lines 67-69 and lines 91-92. So it's exactly as I said: you need to install the necessary qt dev packages before building pyqt.

Comment: What qt dev exactly? Only for PyQt4?

Comment: Qt is modular. Clearly, not all of the modules are currently installed on your system. You need to install the packages that include the qt4-webkit modules, as well as the qt4-webkit-dev packages (which contain all the header files).

Comment: I even did `apt-get install libqt4-*` and there are still errors like `Project ERROR: Unknown module(s) in QT: webkitwidgets webkit`

Comment: If you're on ubuntu, you just need `libqt4-webkit` and `libqt4-dev`. Looking again at your output, it also appears you aren't specifying the correct `qmake`, as all the file paths are pointing at qt5. So use the `--qmake` flag to specify the full path to `qmake-qt4` (or whatever it's called on your system).

Comment: I have `libqt4-webkit` and `libqt4-dev`. I run command:
`python3 configure-ng.py  --qmake /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt4/bin/qmake`
and from my output I can't see that QtWebKit will be build..
`These PyQt4 modules will be built: QtCore, QtGui, QtHelp, QtNetwork,
QtDeclarative, QtScript, QtScriptTools, QtXml, QtOpenGL, QtSql, QtSvg, QtTest,
QtXmlPatterns, phonon, QtDesigner, QtDBus.`

Comment: Here's output with `--verbose`
http://pastebin.com/cxCqkB6f

Comment: Does the file `/usr/include/qt4/QtWebKit/qwebpage.h` exist on your system?

Comment: QtWebKit directory doesn't exist in `/usr/include/qt4/`

Comment: What version of ubuntu are you using? It would be a bug if there's a `libqt4-webkit` package, but no header files provided for it.

Comment: Ubuntu 14.04 LTS
`Linux 3.13.0-48-generic #80-Ubuntu SMP Thu Mar 12 11:16:15 UTC 2015`
But I believe I have upgraded libc6 before.

EDIT: Reinstalled `libqt4-webkit` and nothing changed.

Comment: According to the [ubuntu package search](http://packages.ubuntu.com/), the webkit headers are in a separate package - try installing `libqtwebkit-dev`.

Comment: Finally! `These PyQt4 modules will be built: QtCore, QtGui, QtHelp, QtNetwork,
QtDeclarative, QtScript, QtScriptTools, QtXml, QtOpenGL, QtSql, QtSvg, QtTest,
QtWebKit, QtXmlPatterns, phonon, QtDesigner, QtDBus.` Thanks alot!