# want to start ninja-ide but won't start

Tags: python, ninja-ide

install ninja-ide in my kali Linux, whenever I run this code "ninja-ide" to run it this error keeps on coming.....

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/ninja-ide", line 34, in <module>
  ninja_ide.setup_and_run()
  File "/usr/share/ninja-ide/ninja_ide/__init__.py", line 71, in setup_and_run
  core.run_ninja()
  File "/usr/share/ninja-ide/ninja_ide/core/core.py", line 48, in run_ninja
    from ninja_ide.gui import ide
  File "/usr/share/ninja-ide/ninja_ide/gui/ide.py", line 45, in <module>
    from ninja_ide.core import plugin_services
  File "/usr/share/ninja-ide/ninja_ide/core/plugin_services.py", line 29, in <module>
    from ninja_ide.gui.main_panel import main_container
  File "/usr/share/ninja-ide/ninja_ide/gui/main_panel/main_container.py", line 36, in <module>
    from ninja_ide.gui.main_panel import tab_widget
  File "/usr/share/ninja-ide/ninja_ide/gui/main_panel/tab_widget.py", line 40, in <module>
    from ninja_ide.gui.main_panel import browser_widget
  File "/usr/share/ninja-ide/ninja_ide/gui/main_panel/browser_widget.py", line 27, in <module>
    from PyQt4.QtWebKit import QWebView
ImportError: No module named QtWebKit
```

pls what could be the reason

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29523541/importerror-no-module-named-pyqt4-qtwebkit

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2922711/importerror-no-module-named-qtwebkit

Comment: https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues/3200

Comment: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2253348

Answer (score 0):

You are using a very old .deb that needs pyqt4 with qtwebkit that is no longer available, so I recommend installing it using the source code with the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
    python3-pyqt5.qtwebkit \
    qml-module-qtquick2 \
    python3-pyqt5.qtquick \
    wget \
    unzip \
    ca-certificates \
    python3-setuptools
```

```
wget https://github.com/ninja-ide/ninja-ide/archive/v2.4.zip && unzip v2.4.zip
```

```
cd ninja-ide-2.4 && sudo python3 setup.py install
```